# No TTL for LAYOUT Cache

Tags: magento2, cache, redis

I noticed that Magento Layout module does not provide TTL when saves to cache, so the keys in Redis are not expired.

Example: vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:

```
$this->cache->save($this->serializer->serialize($data), $cacheId, $this->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```

Taking into account the key hash depends on the entity ID (i.e. product/category/page) the cache is bloated with key that will never be evicted.

It all leads to 5GB - 6GB of the cache size by the end of the day.

Can anyone tell what was the reason to implement it like this, and should it be changed?

Comment: For anyone looking for a solution:
You can instruct the Redis backend to automatically add EXPIRE by adding these lines to `app/etc/env.php`

`'auto_expire_lifetime' => 3600,
          'auto_expire_pattern' => '/STRUCTURE_LAYOUT_FRONTEND/', // regexp for keys to auto expire`